# Missing required parameters for [Route: staff.update] [URI: server/{server}/staff/update/{id}]

Tags: laravel

I'm using laravel 6. I have similar Controller with similar views in the same application which works fine. Still cannot find the error even after comparing both.

This is the full error given by Laravel.

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Missing required parameters for [Route: staff.update] [URI: server/{server}/staff/update/{id}]. (View: /var/www/pterodactyl/resources/themes/pterodactyl/admin/users/view.blade.php)
```

Controller:

```
Route::post('/staff/update/{id}', 'StaffController@update')->name('staff.update');
```

Edit Form:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="box box-warning">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
            <h3 class="box-title">Staff System</h3>
        </div>
        <form action="{{ route('staff.update', $user->id) }}" method="POST">
            <div class="box-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="staff" class="control-label">Staff</label>
                    <select id="staff" name="staff" class="form-control">
                        <option value="0">@lang('strings.no')</option>
                        <option value="1" {{ $user->staff ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }}>@lang('strings.yes')</option>
                    </select>
                    <p class="text-muted small">You can enable and disable staff role to this user. He can request an access to servers.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box-footer">
                {!! csrf_field() !!}
                <button class="btn btn-success pull-right">Update</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I do not know what to do, after looking for a day. Can someone help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your `route` wrapped in a `route` group as there is no `{server}` parameter defined in your `route` definition. Ultimately you're not providing the `route` a value for `{server}`, in the same manner you do for `{id}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the error `server/{server}/staff/update/{id}`, you have a previous `URL` parameter `{server}` that is not filled. I have no idea what server should be, i assume you know that.

You can do it as functional arguments

```
route('staff.update', $server, $user->id)
```

Or you can do it as an associative array.

```
route('staff.update', ['server' => $server, 'id' => $user->id])
```